# Data frame linear fit

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a data frame with a bunch of columns. I need to call `lm` function over the column 1 and 2, 1 and 3, and so on. So basically I need to loop over all columns and store the results of the fit as I build the model. The problem I am running into is that:

```
lm(df[1]~df[2], data = df) #doesnt work. In this case df is the data frame object 
                           #and df[1] is the first column.
```

What is a good way to do this in a loop, as in access the columns of `df` in an iterative fashion?

Comment: `lm(df[,1]~df[,2])` remember your commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example of the first column of `df` regressed as the dependent variable against all other columns which i think is what you want..

```
x<-1:5
y<-5:1
df<-data.frame(x,y,x,y,x,y)
df1<-df[,1]
df2<-df[,2:6]
resultslist<-lapply(df2,function(x) (lm(df1~x)))
```

If you were more specific about the coefficients/output you want then this answer could be better

Answer (score 1):

Given that you seem to want to cycle through a number of columns fitting single-term linear models with the response being the first column in the `data.frame`, the following will work

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(110),ncol=11))
.names <- names(dat)
.formulae <- lapply(.names[-1], reformulate, response = .names[1])
results_list <- lapply(.formulae, lm, data = dat)
```